# Checking convergance of improper integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I'm having trouble with this equation in my calculus course.

*Show that:*
$$\int_{0}^{\inf}\frac{dx}{1+x^4}\le \frac{4}{3}$$

I've tried to use the comparison test (unsure if it's called that in English). The equation I tried to compare it to was $\int_{0}^{\inf}\frac{dx}{x^4}$ but that integral does not converge given the limits. I've also considered splitting the integral into smaller sections, but that has not worked either.

Thankful for any help!

Comment: Split the integral at $x = 1$ and do estimates on each. Your approach is on the right track

Comment: @Manifoldski Thanks, I will try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^{1}\frac 1 {1+x^{4}} dx \leq \int_0^{1}1dx =1$.

$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac 1 {1+x^{4}} dx \leq \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac 1 {x^{4}} dx=\frac 1  3$.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to calculate this integral.

Let us define
$$
I=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}  t}{1+t^4},\quad  J=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{t^2}{1+t^4}\,\mathrm{d}  t
$$

The function $t\mapsto \frac{1}{1+t^4}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $\frac{1}{1+t^4}=\mathrm{O}(\frac{1}{t^4})$ as $t$ approaches $+\infty$, we deduce that $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{1+x^4}$ exists by the criterion of domination and by comparison to a convergent Riemann integral.

We perform the change of variable $t=1/u$ in the integral $I$. The change of variable is valid since the mapping $u\mapsto 1/u$ is a strictly decreasing bijective $\mathscr{C}^1$ function between $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$. We obtain
$$
I
=
-\int_{+\infty}^{0} \frac{1/u^2}{1+1/u^4}\,\frac{1}{u^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}  u
=
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{u^{2}}{u^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}  u
=
J.
$$
The function $u\mapsto \mathrm{e}^{u}$ is a strictly increasing $\mathscr{C}^1$ bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $]0,{+\infty}[$, thus the change of variable $t=\mathrm{e}^{u}$ is valid. By making this change of variable in $I$, we obtain an integral of the same nature, and therefore convergent:
$$
I
=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{u}}{1+\mathrm{e}^{4u}}\,\mathrm{d}  u
\quad \text{and similarly}\quad 
J
=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{3u}}{1+\mathrm{e}^{4u}}\,\mathrm{d}  u.
$$
Since $I=J$ we have
$$
2\,I
=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{u}+\mathrm{e}^{3u}}{1+\mathrm{e}^{4u}}\,\mathrm{d}  u
=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-u}+\mathrm{e}^{u}}{\mathrm{e}^{-2u}+\mathrm{e}^{2u}}\,\mathrm{d}  u
=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{ch}(u)}{\mathrm{ch}(2u)}\,\mathrm{d}  u
=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{ch}(u)}{1+2\mathrm{sh}(u)^2}\,\mathrm{d}  u
$$
then
$$
2\,I
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{2}\mathrm{ch}(u)}{1+(\sqrt{2}\mathrm{sh}(u))^2}\,\mathrm{d}  u
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigl[\arctan\bigl(\sqrt{2}\mathrm{sh}(u)\bigr)\Bigr]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr)
=
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
and finaly $I=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

We have
$$
\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4}\leq \frac{4}{3}
\quad \Longleftrightarrow\quad 
\frac{2\pi^2}{16}\leq \frac{16}{9}
\quad \Longleftrightarrow\quad 
\pi^2\leq \frac{128}{9}.
$$
We have $\pi\leq \frac{7}{2}$ therefore $\pi^2\leq \frac{49}{4}\leq \frac{128}{9}$. Finaly
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{1+x^4}\leq \frac{4}{3}.
$$